# Unable to send json data to Java servlet using AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, aem

I am trying to pass json data of a datatable and the email the user inputs to my java servlet. I get a status 200 but no data response. I have my AJAX code here:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/bin/abc/sendrohssearchresult",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data:{
     "email": email,
     "emailSubject": emailSubject
  },
  success: function(status){
      console.log("success",status);
  },
  error:function(error){
      console.log("error",error);
  },
})
```

And my Java servlet:

```
@Component(service= Servlet.class,
        property={
                Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=Send Email of RoHS Search Results",
                "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_POST,
                "sling.servlet.paths="+ "/bin/abc/sendrohssearchresult"
        })
public class RohsEmailServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String emailSubject = request.getParameter("emailSubject");
    }

}
```

I have tried other solutions I've found here on stackoverflow such as JSONify the data, remove *dataType: json*, and adding *contentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;* but still the same result. I am using AEM.

Comment: So? You don't write anything to the response in your handler method. (For what it's worth, dealing with servlets directly is _very_ low-level, and I strongly recommend using a sensible framework like Spring MVC or Micronaut instead. Additionally, you need to read the basics about HTTP transactions, because "contents of body" and "request parameter" are not interchangeable.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I should have mentioned this in my question but I am using Adobe Experience Manager (AEM)

Comment: If the code of your servlet is the entire code, then it makes sense that you don't receive anything in the response, since you are not sending any response in the servlet. Add a logger and see if the values in the email and emailSubject is coming through in your servlet. If it does, then you respond back by using the PrintWriter object which can be obtained through `response.getWriter()`. Since you are using POST method, ensure the CSRF filter and the Referrer Filter are not blocking your requests (in case the request didn't reach the servlet)

Comment: @rakhi4110 thanks! I got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rakhi4110 mentioned, I needed to add `response.getWriter()` in order to receive a data response. So I added:

```
response.getWriter().write("Success Data");
```